# Need the same functionality as a computed property, but I need to be able to update the data after initial change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a situation where I need to update data when it detects changes to a state. The user needs to be able to make further changes this info within a textarea. Using computed properties pulls in the data exactly how I want, but any changes made by the user after this are overridden because the computed property keeps changing this data back to it's initial values. What would be the best way to pull in data initially upon a state change but then allow for editing after that point?

Thanks!

Edit: Updated to what i've tried for @Libby.

```
<textarea v-model="exampleData"></textarea>

computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            item: 'item'
        })

methods: {
    exampleFunction() {
       this.exampleData = this.item;
}

mounted() {
    this.exampleFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `exampleData` in a watcher for `item`:

```
watch: {
  item(value) {
    this.exampleData = value;
  }
}
```

This way you can bind your `exampleData` to the textfield, but changes to the `item` will still affect it.

And if you want `exampleData` to be initially set to the value of `item`, do that in the component's `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
  this.exampleData = this.item;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kvhdgg6u/1)

Comment: this seems to work properly, I'll have to study the documentation to really understand how this works under the hood though, It seems like it's looking for any changes to item, then running a function once and then any changes made after that aren't re ran because items is staying the same. thanks for the help.

Comment: My initial Watcher is working fine, I have another set up in a separate component watching a separate data point but the 2nd one isn't triggering, is there a trick to using multiple watcher in multiple components?

Answer (score 1):

If you set your property in`data`, you can initialize it in `mounted` which only runs once when the page is loaded:

```
data:
   text: null
mounted: ->
   text = "This text is initialized"
```

And then set `v-model` on your textarea

```
<textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
```

So the value of the `textarea` will start out as "This text is initialized", but the user will be able to change it, and those changes will be saved in `text`

Comment: I tried this but it seems like the mounted function runs prior to the component "Getting" the state object, which the mounted function needs to set the local data properly, am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to tell make it wait until the proper info is available before executing?

Comment: The `mounted` function should run after your object is declared in `data`. Can you show your code?

Comment: I updated the original post to show you my logic when trying to use mounted. This hasn't worked for me in the way I thought it would, computed will do it correctly, but then I cannot change the stored data within the textarea(through v-model) as it will always revert back to what the computed property is returning.

Answer (score 1):

Vue already has a built-in solution to handle this if you use the getter/setter syntax for [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

> ```
> computed: {
>   fullName: {
>     // getter
>     get: function () {
>       return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
>     },
>     // setter
>     set: function (newValue) {
>       var names = newValue.split(' ')
>       this.firstName = names[0]
>       this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

As a result, when your state changes you can update the computer property by assigning it a value:

```
// state has changed in text area handler
this.fullName = 'new value'
```